# Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ geometrically.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\
       0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Reflection in the $y$-axis.

I can solve this WITHOUT the reflection meaning I can find the eigenvalue and eigenvector of this. However, I don't know what exactly I should be doing with the reflection. Do I just reflect the eigenvector or do I reflect matrix $A$?

EDIT for the comments:
Do I reflect the eigenvector? Let's solve this problem:

\begin{bmatrix}-1- λ & 0 \\
       0 & 1 - λ
\end{bmatrix}

λ = -1 or 1.

Therefore: Eigenvalue = -1,1 and Eigenvector using -1 will be:

\begin{bmatrix}1 \\
       0
\end{bmatrix}

Do I reflect this eigenvector? Is this what reflection over the Y-axis means? Or Do I only reflect A after plugging in the Eigenvalue for λ?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$
\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\
       0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\
       0 
\end{bmatrix}=-1
\begin{bmatrix}1\\
       0 
\end{bmatrix}
$
and
$
\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\
       0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\
       1 
\end{bmatrix}=1
\begin{bmatrix}0\\
       1 
\end{bmatrix}
$.

Comment: Im sorry... But what is that suppose to show?
Could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: for a matrix $A$ you are seeking scalars $\lambda$ and vectors $v$ such that $Av=\lambda v$.

Comment: Yes. I understand that part.  _Av=λv_ Using this, You can do _(A-λI)X=0_  to solve for λ. Afterwards, you can proceed to solve for the X which is the eigenvector. However, the problem states reflection of A which im unsure of where to reflect. Do I reflect A matrix or do I reflect the eigenvector?

Comment: @LosSiento. You reflect the vector. By multiplying the vector with this matrix it reflects the vector.

Comment: Here is my thought process and excuse me for the poor formatting:

_Av=λv_ -> _(A-λI)X=0_ -> [ 1- λ      0 
                                              0         1-λ ]

Comment: Ahh.. the edit I made didnt make it onto here for some reason... What im trying to say is... If the eigenvector is [0
                                                            -1] and I reflect it to Y, It will be
       [1
        0]?

Comment: [1,0] reflects into [-1,0].

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, what does it mean for a vector $v$ to be an eigenvector of $A$? We know that $Av = \lambda v $ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, but that means for any $t \in\mathbb{R}$ we have that $Atv = tAv = t\lambda v$, and so we have $A tv \in \mathbb{R} v$ where $\mathbb{R} v$ is the set of all multiples of $v$. This means that as a subspace, $A$ takes $\mathbb{R}v$ to $\mathbb{R} v$, or $A(\mathbb{R} v) = \mathbb{R} v$.  Now geometrically, what linear subspaces does a reflection leave invariant?

Comment: Geometrically, to be an eigenvector of _A_, vector _v_ must points to the same direction.

Comment: $v$ points in the same direction as what?

Comment: v must point in the same direction as Av.

Comment: and which $v$ satisfy that condition, geometrically?

Answer (score 0):

The matrix,

\begin{equation}
 A = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\
       0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}

is a reflection across the y-axis. When you multiply a vector by $A$, it gives you the same vector, but reflected across the y-axis.

Its eigenvectors are
$v_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}1\\
       0 
\end{bmatrix}$
and
$v_2=
\begin{bmatrix}0\\
       1 
\end{bmatrix}$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = -1$ and $\lambda_2 = 1$.

There is no reflection necessary if all they are asking for is the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, as they are not asking you to reflect anything.

Comment: What is the whole point of them mentioning its a reflection across the y-axis? Pretty much, I am suppose to find an eigenvector and an eigenvalue such that _AV1_ = _λV1_ and same thing with V2. 

What if its a projection over the X axis? How would I go about solving that?